# How to split an XML string into parts with different keys

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, split

from XML column I wanna try get info.

Every client have more that one `contract_key` in XML, im using `split_part` and `strpos` for get needed information :

```
    select 
application_id,
response_body,
left(Contract_key, strpos(Contract_key, '"') - 1) as Contract_key,
left(AmountR, strpos(AmountR, '<') - 1) as OutstandingAmountR,
left(Avgmonth, strpos(Avgmonth, '<') - 1) as AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount,
from(

select application_id, 
response_body, 
            split_part(response_body, '<OutstandingAmountR>', 2) AmountR,
            split_part(response_body, '<AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount>', 2) Avgmonth,
            split_part(response_body, '<Contract key="', 2) as Contract_key,

from stage_lt.cb_data_execution_entry_details deed, stage_lt.cb_data_execution_entry dee , stage_lt.cb_application_to_execution_entry aee
where deed.execution_entry_id=dee.id and aee.execution_entry_id=deed.execution_entry_id  and dee.provider_name='cb'
and application_id = '2253545') x
;
```

But problem is this function return the first match found:

| ID | Key | amountR | AVGamount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2253545 | 1 | 10000 | 50 |

this client in same XML have more Contract_key:

| ID | Key | amountR | AVGamount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2253545 | 5 | 70000 | 35 |
| 2253545 | 7 | 8000 | 70 |
| 2253545 | ... | ... | ... |

My desired results, by ID get all keys from XML and what info after key until next key :

| ID | Key | amountR | AVGamount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2253545 | 1 | 10000 | 50 |
| 2253545 | 5 | 70000 | 35 |
| 2253545 | 7 | 8000 | 70 |
| 2253545 | ... | ... | ... |

---

HOW xml looks like : Contract key = 1 and Contract key = 9

[XML link](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/y22fbb8e2)

Desired results from this example:

| ID | Contract key | OutstandingAmountR | AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2253545 | 1 | 12320.84 | 224.15 |
| 2253545 | 9 | 3914.13 | 74.96 |

Comment: Using `xmltable()` or `xpath()` will probably be easier and more reliable. But without an example on how the input XML looks like this is nearly impossible to answer

Comment: Hmm, is that the value for a single column in a single row? Because the XML is not well-formed and thus couldn't be stored in a column with the data type `xml`.

Comment: Yes, ` <Contract key="1"> ` and ` <Contract key="9"> ` is in the same column, when I open full xml. 40 spaces from left corner

Comment: Then this can't be an "XML column" as you can't store invalid (not "well-formed")  XML in a column defined with the data type `xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your xml sample data, first one there's no opening tag for `</othercontracts>` and this tag has a bad formed namespace definition `<BatchResponse xmlns="http://katana">` should be like `<BatchResponse xmlns:ns3="http://katana">` (namespace=something) and that prevents document navigation.

Solving that https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/y22fbb8e2 you should treat xml data as such, not using text functions but xml fuctions, so using xmltable function is very simple to query your data, here an example

Having

```
create table public.sample (
    id int4 NULL,
    response_body xml NULL
);

insert into sample values (1, '<responseContainer xmlns:ns2="http://ws.nGCR">
    <ns2:Header>
        <ns2:RequestId>11480644</ns2:RequestId> ... );
```

Query should look like

```
select xmltable.* from
xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://ws.nGCR' AS ns2),
'/responseContainer/ns2:Report/ns2:Registers/ns2:PositiveInfo/BatchResponse/Commands/Command/GenericReport/Data/ExistingContracts/Contract'
  passing (select response_body from sample) 
  columns key text path '@key',
  OutstandingAmountR float8 path 'OutstandingAmountR/text()',
  AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount float8 path 'AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount/text()' );
```

Using xpaths to reach desired data.

And result

[image]

in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html